# Sample datasets for machine learning application in hiring

Tags: machine-learning, uses-of-open-data

As part of a project we need to explore machine learning applications in candidate shortlisting on applied jobs via job boards.

Looking for sample datasets in the area of recruitment to get started.

Any pointers will be helpful.